# ¿Por qué no funciona el overflow: hidden;?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo una prueba para un proyecto. El punto es que deseo que un círculo muy grande sea el fondo de mi header, para esto estoy usando el position de la siguiente manera:

```css
header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 4vw;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

body{
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100vw;
}

.circulo{
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
border: 1px solid black;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<header>asd</header>
<div class="circulo"></div>
</body>
```

Sin embargo el código se rompe y hace el círculo muy grande. Cabe aclarar que es para teléfonos por lo qu estoy usando de plantilla el width del iphone xr. ¿Cómo podría ocultar el desbordamiento?

Comment: no se ve nada dentro del circulo ni del header que provoque un overflow para hiddear, el circulo es de 600x600 como está especificado. que tamaño debería tener?

Comment: Por defecto las posiciones son relativas. No es necesario ser explícito. Por cierto, no puedes hacer un dibujo en paint de cómo quieres que se vea?

Answer (score 0):

Pero porque no metes el circulo dentro del `header` y lo acomodas a tu gusto?

a 600x600px

```css
body{
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
}

header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 4vw;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.circulo{
width: 600px;
height: 600px;
border: 1px solid black;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="circulo"></div>
    Header
</header>
```

O a medida

```css
body{
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
}

header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 4vw;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.circulo{
width: 76px;
height: 76px;
border: 1px solid black;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="circulo"></div>
    Header
</header>
```

o al 100%

```css
body{
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
}

header{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
width: 100%;
padding: 4vw;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.circulo{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border: 1px solid black;
background: green;
border-radius: 50%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="circulo"></div>
    Header
</header>
```